# Egg using geo nodes not working

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I am trying to make an egg using geo nodes not regular modelling.

I did that because I just wanted to test out the attribute statistic node.

Here is my work:

[image: work from attribute statistic]

the result is all the points in the origin of the world

[image]

Comment: this is the node tree in case you can't open the other

Comment: Is your question about the attribute statistic node, or the way to create the egg?

Comment: the way to create the egg

Comment: also its now solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Attribute Statistic* node returns a **single** collective value, derived from the 'Attribute' and 'Geometry' fed to it. So if you use it as the 'Position' input of a *Set Position* node, it will send all points to that single value, (cast to a vector, if necessary).

To get an egg, you probably want to make the X and Y positions of the points some function of their Z position:

[image]

Here's a shot at a nice smooth, circular, egg, with no pinch-points ;)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would call this an egg:

[image]

Here the node `Sine` helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to create an egg if the question is about that.

To get a more oval-shaped sphere you can use a bezier curve to control the shape.  Then you can change the bezier curve and taper it as you like.  Here are the two parts of the node tree, the sphere and the bezier curve.

[image]